# Flink: Loss of lines during writing using DataSink `WritetoCsv()`

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am doing the real-time streaming analysis in flink. I am reading the messages from kafka and doing some processing on it. After processing I am writing the results into a .csv file using `WritetoCsv()` method of Datastream. I am dealing with 3.9 million messages which results into 48232 number of lines of final results that I am writing into a .csv file.

When I am writing to .csv, some of the lines are not written or are partially written to the file, but when I print the same data on eclipse console, I got all the lines of result printed. I am using eclipse local environment for running this flink program.

What can be reason behind the loss of lines during dumping the result into .csv file using `WritetoCsv()`.

Eclipse Java Heap size = 2GB.

Comment: On eclipse you are in local mode. In your experiments with kafka, are you using flink in distributed mode? Because there might be some differences. Maybe you could ellaborate a bit on your problem with some code or some application logic.

Comment: With Kafka, I not using distributed mode. Also I have set the parallelism to 1 and I am processing per message and not using any windowing. My program logic is-> I accept the message in the form of string -> convert it into tuple of 6 fields -> do some simple logical processing line `if-else` processing -> use `out.collect` conditionally to sink the result into .csv file.